# PHP put value of one single textbox in array

Tags: php, arrays, textbox

So I have this "form" and a database with articles. What I want to do is the following:
I have one single textbox called "inputaddtobill", and when the focus is released, a button is automaticly pressed.

now in the textbox, barcodes should be put. and those barcodes refer to the articlename.
Whenever I put a barcode in the textbox the corresponding article should be displayed, and when I put the next barcode in it, there should be 2 articles displayed

here's my html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Verkoop</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/artverklostfoc.js"></script>
<link rel="icon" href="../img/favicon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="kassaverkoop.php?a=b" name="frmkassaverkoop">
<input type='text' onBlur='lostFocus()' name='inputaddtobill' class='inputaddtobill'>
<input type='submit' value='toevoegen' name='butaddtobill' id='butaddtobill' />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my php

```
<?php
include "connect_to_mysql.php";
if(isset($_GET['a']) && $_GET['a'] == 'b')
{
    $input = array($_POST['inputaddtobill']);
    $queryart = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_artikel WHERE FLD_Barcode IN ($input)");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryart))
    {
        echo $row['FLD_Artikel'];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: on side note: use `'$input'` instead of `$input` in your sql query

Comment: And what's the question?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not work.

```
$input = array($_POST[...']);
```

creates an array with a single value at index 0 - the value from $_POST.

You then use $input directly in your query. That means you're using an array in a string context, meaning you'll actually be inserting the word `Array` into your query string and end up with

```
SELECT ... WHERE FLD_Barcode IN (Array)
```

as well, note that even if this could work, you'd be directly inserting user-supplied data into your query string, leaving you open to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).